# how can i overwrite the style of primary-Button in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular6

i would like to change the background-color if i click on the radioButton.

```css
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:visited,
.btn-primary:focus {
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <div class="radiobuttonWidth">
    <p-radioButton [somethink]="some"> </p-radioButton>
  </div>
</div>
```

the hover-Effect works but not the active

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML instead of p-radioButton?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is working for me. Please check you have defined your style.css after bootstrap style import and using **!important** to override bootstrap styling.

```css
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:visited,
.btn-primary:focus {
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: green !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <div class="radiobuttonWidth">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put your stylesheet above the bootstrap css stylesheet

```
<!doctype>
<html>
 <head>
     <style>
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
     </style>
```

Then you style the button with the "btn & btn-primary class"

```
   .btn-primary{
             color: white;
             background-color: red !important;
         }
```

Comment: i would like style the button when active